# Robolectric, android api seems doesn't invoked

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric, junit5

`MediaMetadataRetriever:setDataSource(string)` with empty string must throw **IllegalArgumentException()**.
However, it doesn't throw any Exception if it is started from my **robolectric** test.

**Test class:**

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class MyActivityTest {

    private val context: Context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()

    @get:Rule
    val exception = ExpectedException.none()

    @Test
    fun test_GivenFilePathEmpty_ButNoException() {
        // no exception is expected

        // Given
        val filePath = ""
        // val filePath = null // This should also throw Exception

        // When
        val controller = Robolectric.buildActivity(
                MyActivity::class.java
        ).setup()

        // Then
        assertNotNull(controller.visible())
    }
```

MyActivity.java

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        filePath = ""
        mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(filePath);

    }
```

**MediaMetadataRetriever.java** from AOSP:

```
public void setDataSource(String path) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (path == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    try (FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(path)) {
        FileDescriptor fd = is.getFD();
        setDataSource(fd, 0, 0x7ffffffffffffffL);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fileEx) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    } catch (IOException ioEx) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Is it because robolectric cannot figure out file system?
Or is it because AOSP APIs doesn't really invoked from RobolectricTestRunner?

Answer (score 0):

It is turned out that android API's are not actually invoked via Robolectric.
So I made custom shadow to mock the API.

```
@Implements(MediaMetadataRetriever::class)
class ShadowMediaMetaDataRetriever {

    companion object {
        const val INVALID_FILE_PATH = "invalid_file_path"
    }

    @Implementation
    fun setDataSource(path: String?) {
        if (path == null) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException()
        }
        if (path == INVALID_FILE_PATH) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException()
        }
        if (path == "") {
            throw IllegalArgumentException()
        }
    }
}
```